# binding a textbox on gridfrom

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, xaml

I have a datagrid which is populated from a web service. I want to fill a form based on the selected item in the datagrid.

This is what I use to set the DataContext (Which is a grid)

```
private void PublisherSearchList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{    
    this.PublisherItem.DataContext = (Publisher)PublisherSearchList.SelectedItem;   
}
```

XAML

```
<Grid Name="PublisherItem" Width="390" Margin="5" > 
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <TextBox Name="CompanyName" DataContext="{Binding PublisherName}"
               Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"></TextBox>                    
</Grid>
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to bind your control with properties?
For example if your Publisher class has property Name than you can bind this way

```
DataContext="{Binding Publisher, Path=Name}"
```